# Modal not showing long messages, problem with javascript function arguments

Tags: javascript, html, django, bootstrap-modal

I am facing a problem when I try to show message content in modal. I am trying to build a view which has a list of messages (table), and by clicking a message title, the user would be able to see the message content in modal view. It works for short messages, but for some reason nothing happens with longer messages. I think the issue is with my function 'displayMessage' to which I pass two elements: message title and message content.

Here is the snippet from the table view:

```
    <table id="msg-table" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th id="message-date" scope="col">Date</th>
            <th id="message-content" scope="col">Message</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for message in messages %}
           <tr>
             <td>{{ message.date }}</td>
             <td onclick="displayMessage('{{message.content,}}', '{{ message.title }}')">
               {{ message.title }}
           </tr>
        
          <div id="myModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                   <h5 class="modal-title" id="message-title"></h5>
                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                   </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p id="message-content"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

And this is the function for displaying the Modal:

```
   function displayMessage(message, title) {

     var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
     var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

     // Change the modal text and display
     document.getElementById("message-title").innerHTML = title;
     document.getElementById("message-content").innerHTML = message;
   
     modal.style.display = "block";

     close.onclick = function () {
       modal.style.display = "none";
     }
 
     window.onclick = function (event) {
       if (event.target == modal) {
         modal.style.display = "none";
       }
     }
   }
```

Can anyone help me to identify what am I doing wrong here?
EDIT: I think it is problem with the .innerHTML part. It does not work if the message is multiline item, but not sure how to fix this..

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not send the varialbe via javascript

```
    <table id="msg-table" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th id="message-date" scope="col">Date</th>
            <th id="message-content" scope="col">Message</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for message in messages %}
           <tr>
             <td>{{ message.date }}</td>
             <td onclick="displayMessage('{{message.id}}')">
               {{ message.title }}
           </tr>
        
          <div id="myModal{{message.id}}" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                   <h5 class="modal-title" id="message-title">{{ message.title }}</h5>
                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                   </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p id="message-content">{{message.content}}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

Javascript

```
function displayMessage(id) {
     var modal = document.getElementById("myModal"+id);
     var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

     // Change the modal text and display
     modal.style.display = "block";

     close.onclick = function () {
       modal.style.display = "none";
     }
 
     window.onclick = function (event) {
       if (event.target == modal) {
         modal.style.display = "none";
       }
     }
   }
```

It is because the message title and content is updated with python variable. And you created a modal per a message

thank you

Comment: Hi, thank you for this! I tested it, but it shows the same message content for all messages now in the modal (the first message) so it seems that it creates one modal for all messages. In my example I managed to get short messages to show in the modal, but for longer ones nothing happens.

Comment: Please check tabindex.